# If $f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$ is a probability density function, then $f'(x)\to0$ implies $f(x)\to0$ as $|x|\to\infty$

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, density-function

Let $f:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ be twice continuously differentiable and assume $$\int f(x)\:{\rm d}x=1.$$

How can we conclude that as $|x|\to\infty$ either

1. $f(x)\to0$ and $f'(x)\to0$,
2. $f(x)\to0$ and $f'(x)\not\to0$ or
3. $f(x)\not\to0$ and $f'(x)\not\to0$?

If I'm not missing anything, the only other case would be $f(x)\not\to0$ and $f'(x)\to0$. So, I guess we need to show that this is impossible. Since $f'(x)\to0$ as $|x|\to\infty$ does not necessarily imply that $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)$ even exists, this must have something to do with the integrability condition, right? If this is not sufficient, do we need to impose further conditions?

Comment: @RRL The question is, whether we can conclude that either 1., 2. or 3. must hold (i.e. there is no other case).

Answer (score 2):

> If $f:\mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ is integrable (over $\mathbb{R}$) and
>   $f'(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to +\infty$, then it follows that $f(x) \to 0$.

For proof by contradiction, assume WLOG that $f(x) \not\to 0$ as $x \to +\infty$.  There exists $\beta > 0$ and a sequence $x_n \to +\infty$ such that $f(x_n) \geqslant \beta$. Selecting a subsequence if necessary, we can assume that $x_{n+1} > x_n + \beta.$

Since $f'(x) \to 0$, there exists $a > 0$ such that $-\frac{1}{2} < f'(x) < \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x \geqslant a$, and for all sufficiently large $n \geqslant N$ we also have $x_n > a$.

Thus,

$$\tag{*}\int_a^\infty f(x) \, dx \geqslant \sum_{n=N}^\infty\int_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}}f(x) \, dx > \sum_{n=N}^\infty\int_{x_n}^{x_n + \beta}f(x) \, dx.$$

By the mean value theorem for $x \in (x_n,x_n + \beta$) there exists $c_n \in (x_n,x)$ such that

$$f(x) = f(x_n) + f'(c_n)(x - x_n)> \beta - \frac{1}{2}\beta = \frac{\beta}{2}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\int_{x_n}^{x_n + \beta}f(x) \, dx > \frac{\beta^2}{2},$$

and using (*) we obtain a contradiction,

$$\int_a^\infty f(x) \, dx > \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{\beta^2}{2} = + \infty$$

Comment: How do we know that the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ exist? A continuous function doesn't to have a limit at infinity. Is the reason simply that as long as $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is *any* sequence with $x_n\to\infty$, we know by assumption $\limsup_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)>0$ and hence we may select a subsequence which converges to the limit superior?

Comment: Yes — since $f$ is positive, if it fails to converge to $0$, then the limit is not zero or fails to exist. In either case limsup is positive and is the limit of the images of a subsequence.

Comment: I guess that (in order for $(\ast)$ to hold) we need to assume $x_1\ge a$ (which is clearly no problem). Moreover, I guess the first inequality in $(\ast)$ is due to the possible gap between $r$ and $x_1$, right? (Since if $x_1=r$, then $(\ast)$ should be an equality.)

Comment: Yes it could be an equality, but what is important is the second relation which is an inequality

Comment: At which point did you use the integrability? I guess at the end, but even when $\int f(x)\:{\rm d}x=\infty$ this would be a contradiction (since your last equation would read $\infty>\infty$).

Comment: Standard argument. We are given that the integral $\int_a^\infty f(x) \, dx$ is finite. The integrand is nonnegative and the integral exceeds $\sum_{n=1}^m \beta^2/2$ for any $m$. Taking the limit as $m \to \infty$ results in a contradiction. My notation above just saves on words.

Comment: No, you didn't get my point. What I mean is that even when $\int_a^\infty f(x)\:{\rm d}x=\infty$, $$\int_a^\infty f(x)\:{\rm d}x> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\beta^2}{2} = \infty$$ would still be a contradiction.

Comment: Ok. I accept that. The first question was at which point did I use the integrability. The answer is when I started writing (*) knowing the integral is finite by hypothesis. I was never intending to get $\infty > \infty$ as a contradiction.

Comment: Even in $(\ast)$, I don't see why $(\ast)$ should fail to hold when $\int_a^\infty f(x)\:{\rm d}x=\infty$. Just assume $x_1=a$ (such that there is no gap). Then by definition of the Riemann integral, $$\int_a^\infty f(x)\:{\rm d}x=\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^bf(x)\:{\rm d}x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}}f(x)\:{\rm d}x$$ and this would still hold if the left-hand side is $\infty$.

Comment: I guess it's obvious, but maybe you can explain to me what I'm missing.

Comment: What you are missing is that strict order need not be preserved with limits, even in the extended real numbers. If $a_n > b_n$ for all $n$ then the most one can conclude is $\lim a_n \geqslant \lim b_n$. Example (1): $1/n > 0$ but $\lim 1/n = 0$; Example (2): $n^2 > n$ but $\lim n^2  = \lim n = + \infty$.  As you see $\int_a^\infty f(x) \, dx = \infty$ has the meaning $\lim_{b \to \infty} \int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \infty$.

Comment: Actually, that's clear to me. What confused me was the strict inequality in your $(\ast)$, which should also be an $\ge$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what your WLOG argument at the beginning is?

Comment: I’m just considering the case where $x \to +\infty$ and not the case where $x \to -\infty$, which can be handled in a similar way.  Rather than WLOG it would be better to say it is enough to consider that case.

Comment: Do you agree to what I wrote about your inequality $(\ast)$? Shouldn't the strict $>$ actually be an $\ge$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d:  Note that $[x_n, x_n+ \beta]$ is a strict subset of $[x_n,x_{n+1}]$ -- as I said we can always construct a sequence where $x_{n+1} > x_n + \beta$.  We have $f(x) \geqslant 0$ since you wrote the range as $[0,\infty)$. Unless $f$ is identically $0$ on the interval we must have $\int_{x_n}^{x_{n+1} } f(x) \, dx > \int_{x_n}^{x_{n} +\beta} f(x) \, dx $. The inequality must be strict for the sums in (*)  as well  unless $f(x) = 0$ for all sufficiently large $x$.  It it is then it can be examined as a special case but it certainly does not affect the outcome here.

Comment: I'm sorry for hanging on such a simple thing so long, but while it's clear to me that $\int_{x_n}^{x_{n+1} } f(x) \, dx > \int_{x_n}^{x_{n} +\beta} f(x) \, dx$, the strict inequality should turn into an inequality for the infinite sum in $(\ast)$. As you've said, the strict order doesn't need to be preserved. In any case, $\ge$ is all we need in $(\ast)$, if I'm not missing something.